# get information from devices which connect to same wifi hot spot

Tags: wifi-hotspot

After create public wifi hot spot through phone. How to get device information from those who are trying to connect the hot spot?

Answer (score 1):

There's an app on Play Store called Fing that's probably close to what you want. You don't even need to be the host, it detects all devices on your network.